# Advice on using word count javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a function that should generate a random paragraph, but I would like to get some advice on how can I display the number of times each word in the paragraph is used, once the button is clicked.... do you use something like a counter variable?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var article = ["the", "be", "let", "done", "any"];
var noun = ["boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"];
var verb = ["drove","jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped"];
```

Comment: Thought of doing `article[Math.floor(Math.random() * article.length)]`? What if you add an article and forget to change that number?

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression `match`, and get the length of the result for each searched word.

For example:

```
var countThe = sentence.match(/the/g).length;
```

**update:** More generally:

```
function countOccurances(sentence, word){
    var reg = RegExp(word,'g');
    return sentence.match(reg).length
}
```

With a test:

```
var sentence = "This is the sentence that we are going to look in for testing -- not the real thing."                                                                      ;
alert(countOccurances(sentence, "the"))
```

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps a split could be faster? `sentence.split("the").length - 1`

Comment: if you need words you need to check that there are spaces or something before and after the word. if you are ok with "before" being counted as "be" then ignore this comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `string.match` is probably the easiest method.

```
function checkFor(wordsArray,inString){
    returnObject={};
    for(var i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++){
        returnObject[wordsArray[i]]=inString.match(new RegExp("([^A-Za-z]|^)"+wordsArray[i]+"([^A-Za-z]|$)","gi")).length
    }
    return returnObject;
}
checkFor(["hi","peter"],"I would like to say to you Peter, hi howdy hello, I think hi is the best of these greetings for you");
Returns Object {hi: 2, peter: 1};
```

Then just run this on each of the arrays with the sentance as the inString argument

EDIT:
To explain what this does,

- It is a function where you can pass in an array of words to look for and it will output an associative array or object (JavaScript doesn't distinguish between the two) of the counts of those values
- The function loops through each element in the words array
- It then runs the regular expression `/([^A-Za-z]|^)wordGoesHere([^A-Za-z]|$)/gi` which is a bit complicated I admit
- the regular expression checks for "WordGoesHere" and makes sure that is is a word not just part of another word, the `([^A-Za-z]|^)` checks that the character before the word is not in the set A-Z or is the start of the string so basically allows spaces, commas, full stops and any other punctual thing you can imagine. `([^A-Za-z]|$)` does the same except it checks for the end of the string
- the gi is a flag stating a global search (don't just stop after the first match) and case insensitive

[This site](http://regexr.com) I find is invaluable for testing regular expressions

Comment: I'm actually new to javascript, two months in. I think I'm getting what you are saying. Right now I'm trying to put the pieces together and show you if I'm close to what your telling me. for(var i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++){
        returnObject[wordsArray[i]]=inString.match(new RegExp

Comment: I would then input the sentence I have created into that argument. And for it to display would I have to add something inside the textarea. Hope I'm not confusing you

Answer (score 0):

This will count the frequency of all words in a string.

```
function countWords(s) {
  var a = s.match(/\w+/g);
  var counts = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var elem = a[i];
    if(!counts[elem]) counts[elem] = 1;
    else counts[elem]++;
  }
  return counts;
}
```